# What's the difference between update() after findOne() and direct update()?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Suppose I have a people collection like this:

```
{
    {'_id': 1, 'name': 'Tom', 'age': 22}, 
    {'_id': 2, 'name': 'Joe', 'age': 30}
}
```

***code 1:***

```
p = db.people.find_one({'_id': 1})
db.people.update(p, {'$inc': {'age': 1}})
```

***code 2:***

```
db.people.update({'_id': 1}, {'$inc': {'age': 1}})
```

I found code 1 and code 2 are different in pymongo.
But I don't know the difference. Can anybody tell me?

EDIT:

I got it.

Json documents in pymongo are out-of-order. So `p = db.people.find_one({'_id': 1})` may not return exact the same document as document whose '_id' field's value is 1. `db.people.update(p, {'$inc': {'age': 1}})` may not find any document satisfies query p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `code 1` example retrieves the full document with `_id` of `1`, and then does an update using the full document (saved in variable `p`) as the search criteria.  The side effect here is that if any field has changed in the document stored in the database between doing the `find_one()` and the `update()`, your update won't find the document.

So this is equivalent to doing:

```
db.people.update({'_id': 1, 'name': 'Tom', 'age': 22}, {'$inc': {'age': 1}})
```

Your `code 2` example is performing an update using the search criteria that `_id` is `1`.  This update will always succeed as long as the document exists.

Answer (score 1):

If omit details **code 1** does 2 queries while **code 1** does 1 query

```
1.   client       mongodb          2. client        mongodb

           find_one                         update
        ------------->                   ------------->
           document
        <-------------


           update
        ------------->
```

Comment: It's true that the first example does an extra query, but a more important detail is that the updates are actually using different search criteria.